# Using a query count inside an afterSave trigger (Parse.com cloud code)

Tags: parse-platform

I have a small afterSave trigger in my parse cloud code. The trigger just re-counts items that are flagged as deleted=false.

When I update my object, the count goes just fine, except when I update the deleted flag. It seems like the count is considering objects BEFORE the save event, which is not what I would expect from an "afterSave" trigger.

On the other hand, by using a "find" instead of a "count" on the very same query, I will always get the right number of objects. Of course the "find" way will go just when the query stays below 1000 objects.

Is there something wrong in my code? Is it the expected behavior? Is it a bug? Any alternative way to count objects the right way?

Thank you so much for your attention

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("BranchLike", function(request) {
    console.log("Managing branchLike after save...");
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var branch = request.object.get("branch");
    var branchLikeClass = Parse.Object.extend("BranchLike");
    var type = request.object.get("type");
    var branchLikeQuery = new Parse.Query(branchLikeClass);
    branchLikeQuery.equalTo("branch",branch);
    branchLikeQuery.equalTo("deleted",false);
    branchLikeQuery.equalTo("type",type);       
    branchLikeQuery.count({
        success: function(count) {
            console.log("count = "+count);    //works fine except on "delete" flag updates
            /* ... */
        },
        error: function(error) {
            /* ... */
        }
    });
    branchLikeQuery.find({
        success: function(branchLikes) {
            console.log("ALTERNATIVE COUNT = "+branchLikes.length);    //works fine when having less than 1000 objects
        },
        error: function(error) {
            /* ... */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, do you have some new info? I have the same problem